# How can implement infinite HorizontalScrollView in Android

Tags: android, scrollview, horizontal-scrolling

I used buttons in `HorizontalScrollView`. normally when `scroll right`, after the last
button I have to `scroll left`. But I want to know when `scroll right`
after the `last button` it should show the `first button`. not want to
`scroll left`.
**just as circle.**

thanks

Comment: Screen doesn't rotate like a globe.

Comment: hi miuranga, i am facing the same problem in horizontal scroll view. I have 43 image and want to display it as circular and infinite. Have you done that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to do that trick with horizontalScrollView, i thought that it's impossible, but i know one widget, that maybe can help you
http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/
unfortunatly, it's only vertical, and you can't put buttons into it. I tried to make it horizontal, but failed. Maybe, if you will need, you'll get more luck